# Can I define a measure $\mu$ only through the values it takes in the elements of the generator of its $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

In other words,

Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{B}$ a family of pairwise disjoint subsets of $X$ such that $\bigcup \mathcal{B} = X$.

Denote by $\sigma(\mathcal{B})$ the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{B}.$

Let $\mu$ be a function from $\sigma(\mathcal{B})$ to the real numbers ($\mu: \sigma(\mathcal{B})\to \mathbb{R}$) satisfying:

$\mu(B) \geq 0$;

$\mu(X) = 1$;

$\mu(\bigcup_i B_i) = \sum_i\mu(B_i)$. for $(B_i)$ a countable collection of elements of $\mathcal{B}.$

**Question**

Is $\mu$ a (probability) measure?

**Answer**
As mentioned in an answer, it is not the case in general. 
if $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\pi$-system (or an algebra as in the link below) the answer is yes.

The answer is basically Carathéodory's extension theorem, which  Wikipedia has a simple article explaining it: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory's_extension_theorem

Comment: (1) The title and question seem unrelated. (2) Condition 3 should require the $\{B_i\}$ to be a countable collection of mutually disjoint sets.

Comment: Any suggestion for another tittle? I am also unhappy with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, a measure must have a sigma-algebra as a domain. So I assume what you're really asking is whether or not the function $\mu$ you've defined above can be uniquely extended to a measure. Without additionally structure for your set $\mathcal{B}$, this is not the case. If in addition $\mathcal{B}$, were a pi-system, then yes your $\mu$ would uniquely extend to a measure. Have a look at Carathéodory's extension theorem.

Comment: The OP says that $\mathcal{B}$ is a partition of $X$ which is quite boring and trivial case.